# npx webpack generate wrong license

Tags: reactjs, webpack

In my package.json is setting like this:

```
"license": "Proprietary",
"private": true,
```

but my final js compiled script contain license text like this:

```
/*! *****************************************************************************
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use
this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the
License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

THIS CODE IS PROVIDED ON AN *AS IS* BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, EITHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION ANY IMPLIED
WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF TITLE, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
MERCHANTABLITY OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.

See the Apache Version 2.0 License for specific language governing permissions
and limitations under the License.
***************************************************************************** */
```

but I except license text that code is private and not under `Apache License 2.0.`
Am I dooing something wrong in config?